# thread safe random access circular array in java?

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, circular-buffer

I need to cache the least recent result (say 10,000) of a concurrent system, and random access them.
Since most of concurrent cache are based on linked list, I'm wondering if there is a thread safe random access circular array in java?

Comment: Can you give more details on how you need to use it? In example, could Guava's in-memory cache work for you?

Comment: Assuming by "random access" you mean access by index? If so, is it by LRU order? If so, why do you need that? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Daniele Local cache for fail over, write operation is much more than read

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, by index, but restriction is weaker than LRU, cause it's only used for failover

Comment: The locking issues of a linked list shouldn't be a problem in a well designed cache. If you need LRU then [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap) or [Guava's Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) should suffice. If you can leverage a smarter eviction policy, then [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) is preferrable. See [benchmarks](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks#server-class).

Comment: @BenManes No, I cannot use linked list, random access is a must

Comment: What does that mean? The random access of the map entries is supported.

Comment: @BenManes The problem is, i don't have a key to describe requests: every request is different with each others, they are basically user actions. So i decide to cache a list of response and combine them as a failover response.

Comment: Then I suppose a lock-free circular ring buffer and fifo or clock eviction is a reasonable strategy.

Comment: You can use AtomicReferenceArray to build your cache on top of.

Comment: can you explain how you "random access" your items? I assume you would use some sort of key?

Comment: @los how are random access and "failover" related?

Comment: @los how are "random access" and "failover" related? Again I ask, what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

For caches without timeout, I often use the `ConcurrentHashMap`. You may also take a look at the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: According to the document, copyOnWriteArrayList is more efficient when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations. But we have much more write than read

Comment: Then you may use a traditional array and synchronize access to it: ```List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>()); ```

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of [CircularFifoQueue](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/index.html) in the Apache Commons Collections library. It contains a get() method for random access. For a thread-safe version, you can wrap its instance with the [SynchronizedQueue](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/SynchronizedQueue.html) wrapper.
Another solution is the cyclic ArrayList/Vector implementation, [described in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659792/circular-arraylist-extending-arraylist).